# Numerical number pattern. and if then else in octave / matlab

Tags: matlab, octave, numerical-methods, sequences, sequential

I'm trying to get a numerical repeating number pattern like this **1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4...** I'm using Octave 3.8.1 which is like matlab

I tried

```
t=20 %note this number will vary 
a=mod(x,5)
```

but **a is 1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4**

I know I can do odd and even numbers using the code below

```
for ii=1:20 %note this number will vary 
    if mod(ii,2)==0
                %number is even
    else
                %number is odd
    end
end
```

But how can I do it with 4 separate number choices of 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>> t=20 %note this number will vary
t =  20
>> maxValue=4; %repeat the numbers 1..maxValue
>> x=0:t-1 %I think this is what you meant to do...
x =

    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19

>> a=mod(x,maxValue)+1 %cycle through 0..3 and add 1
a =

   1   2   3   4   1   2   3   4   1   2   3   4   1   2   3   4   1   2   3   4
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want to do is use `repmat':

```
octave> repmat (1:4, [1 5])
ans =

   1   2   3   4   1   2   3   4   1   2   3   4   1   2   3   4   1   2   3   4
```